# Conjugacy classes of $P\Gamma L(2,q)$

Tags: gr.group-theory, permutation-groups

$\DeclareMathOperator\PGaL{P\Gamma L}\DeclareMathOperator\GF{GF}$May I know whether there are any developments made on the conjugacy classes of $\PGaL(2,q)$ where $q$ is a prime power but not a prime? Also, as there are cycle types in $\PGaL(2,q)$ which does not follow directly from the linear group counterpart (i.e. $[1,3,6]$ in $\PGaL(2,9)$ which does not seem to be derived from $\mathrm{PGL}(2,9)$ but it exists under the action $z \mapsto (z^3 + x + 1)/(z^3 +1)$ on $\GF(9)^*$ where $x \in \GF(9)$ with the defining relation $x^2 =2$.) Is there a tangible reason as to how it behave in this manner?

Comment: I'm not sure what the action is to which you refer in the second half of the question. The function that you give doesn't make sense to me.  In general, though, I would have thought there is no particular reason why the set of cycle types in $P\Gamma L(2,9)$, for any non-trivial action, should coincide with the set of cycle types in $PGL(2,9)$ -- there are a whole bunch more elements to play with, after all.

Comment: If it helps, the conjugacy classes of $P\Gamma L(n,q)$ were worked out by G.E. Wall in a paper entitled CONJUGACY CLASSES IN PROJECTIVE AND SPECIAL LINEAR GROUPS.

Comment: @NickGill I think the function makes sense, note that $z\mapsto z^3$ is the Frobenius automorphism of $\text{GF}(9)$ which extends the action by linear fractional transformations of $\text{PGL}(2,9)$ on $\text{GF}(9)\cup\{\infty\}$.

Comment: ... but this cycle type $[1, 3, 6]$ is already achieved for the simpler permutation $z\mapsto z^3+1$.